# Create a Static / Global Collection in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a Java/C++ developer who is doing an AngularJS project.

In AngularJS, I need to create a collection (e.g. an array) that I can access from various controllers and that doesn't need to be repopulated every time an controller is reloaded.

In Java, I would create a static class that holds the collection an populate it lazily the first time it is requested. Any subsequent calls would have access to the already created collection. (here's a very simple example).

```
    class MyCollectionClass {
        private volatile static ArrayList<Items> s_items = null;    
        public static synchronized List<Items> getItems() {
            if (s_items == null)
                s_items = Foo.getItemsFromNetwork(); // blocking call
            return s_items;
        }
    }

// elsewhere in the code

    List<Items> l = MyCollectionClass.getItems();
```

How do I do something similar in AngularJS? I don't find the documentation very clear on this.

Comment: You need a service. Lots of good tutorials on what we call services or factories in AngualrJS. Just create a JSON to be consumed in a service, and wrap it in a promise. Lots of examples out there on the subject. https://www.google.fr/search?q=anuglarjs+promise+json+factory&oq=anuglarjs+promise+json+factory&aqs=chrome..69i57.6610j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @ChristianBonato I'm actually not even concerned about it being synchronous at this point. I experimented with using a service with a member that I thought would be static, but it is destroyed and recreated every time I reload the controller.

Comment: I just found some documentation defining singleton in Javascript, and it's quite different than Javascript: "Such an object is also sometimes called singleton. In "classical" languages such as Java, singleton means that you can have only one single instance of this class at any time, you cannot create more objects of the same class. In JavaScript (no classes, remember?) this concept makes no sense anymore since all objects are singletons to begin with."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS you can create a Service and follow the same principle you apply in Java (for instance).

In AngularJS services are singleton, so the same collection can be reused everywhere the service is injected.

See the sample below where a service is created and two controllers. These 2 controllers use the same collection. *(Many other good solutions can be found out there, and many others where no good-practice approaches are applied)*

How goes the flow:

1- The service is created with a collection in `null`.

2- The controller 1 (`ctrl1`) is created (`service` is injected) and a check is peformed in order to see if the collection in service is `null`. If so, initialized it with the following collection `['element1-Controller1', 'element2-Controller1']`. As the collection is `null` this new collection is set.

3- The controller 2 (`ctrl2`) is created (`service` is injected) and a check is peformed in order to see if the collection in service is `null`. If so, initialized it with the following collection `['element1-Controller2', 'element2-Controller2']`. As the collection is **not** `null` this new collection is **not** set.

4- Conclusion: `service` is singleton and the same collection can be reused as needed.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])

  // a singlenton instance of this will be created and shared accross all components of the application
  .service('service', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.exp = {
      collection: null,
      setCollection: fnSetCollection,
      getCollection: fnGetCollection
    };

    return self.exp;

    function fnSetCollection(collection) {
      self.exp.collection = collection;
    }

    function fnGetCollection() {
      return self.exp.collection;
    }

  })

  .controller('ctrl1', function(service) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.wizard = {
      getCollection: fnGetCollection
    };

    init();

    return vm.wizard;

    function init() {
      if (!fnGetCollection()) {
        service.setCollection(['element1-Controller1', 'element2-Controller1'])
      }
    }

    function fnGetCollection() {
      return service.getCollection();
    }
  })

  .controller('ctrl2', function(service) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.wizard = {
      getCollection: fnGetCollection
    };

    init();

    return vm.wizard;

    function init() {
      if (!fnGetCollection()) {
        service.setCollection(['element1-Controller2', 'element2-Controller2'])
      }
    }

    function fnGetCollection() {
      return service.getCollection();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="ctrl1 as ctrl1">
    <span> Collection in controller 1</span>
    <br /><br /> {{ctrl1.getCollection()}}
    <div>
<br /><br />

      <div ng-controller="ctrl2 as ctrl2">
        <span> Collection in controller 2</span>
        <br /><br /> {{ctrl2.getCollection()}}
        <div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and comprehensive answer. I'll check it out and if it works give the checkmark.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to make any tweak you need in order to get it working according to your needs ;)

Comment: I implemented this with one controller and I notice that when I refresh the page that uses the controller, it reloads the service and thus the collection. Isn't there a way to keep the collection cached between refreshes?

Comment: Sure! Use [localstorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage). Save the data in the browser localStorage and then when the service initialises retrieve the data from the localstorage and set it in the variable.

Comment: @paiego I forgot to mention that reloading the controller is not necessarily reloading the page. A controller is reloaded when its scope is destroyed and then created again (for instance user goes out of the view handled by the controller and then enter in it again). That case is covered by a simple service. What you're trying to do is persist the information in order to have it available once the entire application is reloaded.

Comment: The scope of a service is still unclear to me. It's often referred to as a singleton so by that I assume it's lifetime is that of the session.

Comment: It happens. It's OK when you are learning AngularJS. Services are singleton because they are created only once in when the application is loaded. But the application is loaded every time the user press `F5` ;) Imagine a server which is restarted, when it initializes again all services  have to search on DB (localstorage in a web browser) what was stored previously. That same principle is applied here.

Comment: @paeigo - If you need a good wrapper for localstorage, there is angular-locker, which simplifies the process and has the ability to sync your controller's $scope with localStorage : https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker

Comment: Also, if your data is really static, i.e. does not have to be fetched from a server and has to be accessed/consumed by the whole app (every controller, service, etc), you can rely on a simple JSON declaration (as global JS variable), outside and prior to AngularJS, that will avoid all the AngularJS boilerplate a service requires.

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs services and factories are singeltons which fits perfectly for this case. Create a service which loads data to the array on creation and then expose that array to consumers

```
angular.module('app').factory("exampleServ", function(){
       var s_items = [];
       var getItems = function(){
            return s_items;
       };
       var loadData = function(){
           //load your data here
           s_items = data;
       };

       //invoke the method which will make sure the items is loaded to the array
       loadData();
       return {
            getItems: getItems
       }
    });
```

Then use the service in your controller `exampleServ.getItems();`